# how to resolve this error in xamarin.forms The type 'ObfuscationAttribute' exists in both

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget, .net-standard-2.0, refit, leadtools-sdk

The type 'ObfuscationAttribute' exists in both 'Leadtools, Version=21.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cf889f53ea9b907' and 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

I'm just installed Leadtools.Camera.Xamarin NuGet in my existing application and getting the above error. In my existing App I'm using refit nuget as well. and this error came with RefitStubs.g.cs file .why this error occurring and how to resolve the above error in Xamarin.Forms. And the used version is 4.8.0.1821.

Comment: Is this a warning or an error?  Do you get it during compilation?

Comment: error. yes during compilation

Answer (score 0):

I tested by adding the Refit nuget package to our CameraDemo that’s shipped with LEADTOOLS 21 and building the project. This did not cause any compilation errors, even when adding code that uses the Refit classes in the C# code of the project.

This project is available with the full SDK installation under this folder:
LEADTOOLS21\Examples\Xamarin\CameraDemo

This means the problem is not likely related to using Refit and Leadtools.Camera.Xamarin together, but is trigged by something else in your project.

I recommend first to try to update your Visual Studio and its dependencies to the latest version.

If that doesn’t solve the problem, try to isolate the problem is a small test project that contains all the references from your main project but without the actual code (skeleton project, but with full references).

If this skeleton project triggers the same problem, send it to support@leadtools.com with details about the problem and our support staff will investigate it and get back to you.